# Upgraded from Marionette 1.8.3 to 2.0.1, getting error Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I upgraded from Marionette 1.8.3 to 2.0.1 as I was having problems with view events being destroyed on my ItemViews but I now get the error at line 2869 of lib\backbone.marionette.js:

var globalCh = **Backbone.Wreqr.radio**.channel('global');

error: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

I was using version 1.3.1 of Backbone.Wreqr but I still get the error.

Things I have tried:

- I have tried using the files without Wreqr & Babysitter included but still get the error.
- I have added Wreqr and Babysitter to the paths in require_config but my version of Wreqr seems to get overridden by another(don't know where this comes from) that doesn't contain Wreqr.radio

I have uninstalled Backbone.Wreqr and installed Backbone.Radio and changed the line above to:

var globalCh = **Backbone.Radio**.channel('global');

I don't really want to do this as we tend to use the downloaded versions as they are without any changes.

Is there something specific that I should be installing along with the upgraded Marionette 2.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the js [backbone.babysitter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter/master/lib/backbone.babysitter.js) and [backbone.wreqr](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr/master/lib/backbone.wreqr.js) to your folder where you store your js or if you are using bower just  **`bower install marionette`** he already makes downloading marionette and all its dependencies.

After doing are is the require all files in the following order:

- [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js)
- [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js)
- [backbone.babysitter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter/master/lib/backbone.babysitter.js)
- [backbone.wreqr](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr/master/lib/backbone.wreqr.js)
- [backbone.marionette](http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette.js)

By doing so think you do not will have more that mistake.

Hope this helps